# Problemas al ejecutar comando mysql -u -p

Tags: mysql, unix, ssh

Tengo un problema ya hace unos dias he intentado de todo y no he podido dar con la solución.

En mi servidor donde esta alojado mi DB en MySQL al momento de ejecutar de ingresar por MySQL

`mysql -u -p`

Me muestra el siguiente error

`mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'general_log=1'`

Revisando el .ini veo que que si esta declaro la variable log_general

`general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1`

posdata: El ini esta en `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` porque usa un `!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` en el archivo my.cnf

Es mas si borro ese linea (general_log) y lo he colocado en valor 0 (en off) me sigue apareciendo ese mismo mensaje, pienso que esta llamando de otra parte pero no se de donde, no se si me pueden dar opciones donde mas podria revisar ya que me preocupa que no pueda ejecutar nada por aquí y no pueda usar Shells.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me sale cuando coloco mi usuario, no me permite ingresar el -p

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me sale cuando coloco mi `which mysql`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @kacospro Me devuelve esto:  /usr/bin/mysql

Comment: @kacospro me devuelve esto `mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'general_log=1'`

Comment: @kacospro se instalo hace años, es una Servidor antiguo solo que revisando el log y la configuración del .ini (my.cnf) algo se movió que no lo encuentro.

Comment: @kacospro que mas se puede revisar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de darle vuelta mil veces al problema logre encontrar la solución al problema.

El error estaba en el formato del archivo mysql.cnf (que es para ejecutar mysql en consola) estaba en DOS y por eso no lo leía.

Lo que realice es darle vi al archivo mysql.cnf y lo converti a formato UNIX con los siguientes comandos:

```
vi ./mysql.cnf
:set ff=unix
:set nobomb
:wq
```

No tuve la necesidad de reiniciar el servicio de MySQL.

Espero que este post le sea de utilidad, me tomo tiempo encontrar el error.
Gracias, vibras!

Answer (score 0):

Noto que no ingresas el nombre del usuario.
Para iniciar sesión requieres de al menos el valor al parámetro usuario `-u` y de la contraseña del usuario para localhost `-p`:

```
 mysql -u NOMBRE_DEL_USUARIO -p
```

Paso seguido debes ingresar la contraseña de dicho usuario, dado que como comento, el caso sencillo que estas usando es en localhost.

Por default el usuario es `root` y no tiene contraseña:

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

A menos que hayas modificado estos datos durante la instalación

Comment: Publique en tu comentario la imagen donde coloco mi -u usuario -p.

No me permite insertar la -p

Comment: @BiancoVidalSaavedra Tu no puedes modificar la respuesta de esa forma, estas atentado contra ella. si deseas añadir informacion edita tu pregunta y añadela alli

Comment: @eyllanesc Entendido, tengo recién un día ya estoy aprendiendo, gracias por la aclaración!